# how to select a line end with } using regex?

Tags: regex

This is my input :

```
\frac{P}{H\textsuperscript{o\textsubscript2}}
```

I want to select a whole using regex. and get a text inside the grouping `{...}`.
In first bracket Should contains single character only. in next bracket multiple characters.
Only two brackets.

My regex:

```
\\frac\{(.)\}\{([^\}]{2,})\}
```

My regex select upto:

```
\frac{P}{H\textsuperscript{o\textsubscript2}
```

not selecting the last `}`. wt i do?

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Give a bit more context. Which language do you use (or is it a texteditor)? This does look like a defined format, is there a parser for it?

Comment: @stema : i am using C#.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another `}` at the last in your regex.

```
\\frac\{(.)\}\{([^\}]{2,}})}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jC4qF9/5)

OR

Check for balanced brackets like this,

```
\\frac\{(.)\}(\{((?:[^{}]|(?1))*)})
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jC4qF9/6)